# Cannot create file or directory in documents folder in iOS sandbox

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift3

I'm making a game on `iPad` (v10.2.1) with `Xcode(version 8.2.1)` and while I'm trying to save some data in documents folder in the sandbox, I found that all ways I tried failed: `createDirectory` and `createFile(using file manager)`, and writeToUrl(using `NSData`). I ran the program on 2 iPads and 1 iPhone and no success.

I was able to read from a plist I created, and convert it to a dictionary, using the function `convertDataFrom()`.

I'm new to data persistence or file manipulation and my game stuck here. would appreciate any help!

```
func loadData()->NSDictionary{
    let fm = FileManager()

    let sourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Data", withExtension: "plist")!
    var appSupportDir = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as? NSURL
    appSupportDir = appSupportDir!.appendingPathComponent("UserData", isDirectory: true) as NSURL?
    let urlForSave = (appSupportDir!.appendingPathComponent("Data.plist"))!


    //load data, or if file doesn't exist yet, create one
    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false

    if fm.fileExists(atPath: urlForSave.absoluteString, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
        let data = convertDataFrom(url: urlForSave)
        print("data file exists")
        print(isDirectory)

        return data as NSDictionary

    } else {
        do { try fm.createDirectory(atPath: appSupportDir!.absoluteString!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil) }catch let Error {
            print("create directory failed")
            print(Error)
        }

        let originalData = NSData.init(contentsOf: sourceUrl)
        print("\(urlForSave)")
        do { try originalData?.write(toFile: urlForSave.absoluteString, options: .atomic) } catch let Error {
            print(Error)
        }
        if (!fm.createFile(atPath: urlForSave.absoluteString, contents: originalData as Data?, attributes: nil)) {
            fatalError("file creation failed")
        }

        let data = convertDataFrom(url: urlForSave)
        print("\(data)")
        print(isDirectory)

        return data as NSDictionary
    }

}

func convertDataFrom(url: URL)->Dictionary<String, Any> {
    let dictionary = NSDictionary.init(contentsOf: url) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    return dictionary
}
```

> Error messages for "createDirectory": Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “UserData” in the
>   folder “Documents”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7F41E0D-D3F6-489B-A59E-B7AC401EC402/Documents/UserData/,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x174053f50 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7F41E0D-D3F6-489B-A59E-B7AC401EC402/Documents/UserData/Data.plist
>
> and for "createFile" (fatalError if createFile fails) Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “Data.plist” doesn’t
>   exist."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F7F41E0D-D3F6-489B-A59E-B7AC401EC402/Documents/UserData/Data.plist,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x174055bd0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2
>   "No such file or directory"}} fatal error: file creation failed: file
>   /Users/chanwu/Desktop/Math_DownStairs/Math_DownStairs/

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks to see if `urlForSave` (the final file) exists, and if it doesn't, you then try to create the UserData directory.

If the final file doesn't exist, but the UserData directory does, I would expect the exact outcome you describe.

You should probably change your test to see if the UserData directory exists instead of testing for the final file. That way if the directory doesn't exist you'll create it, and then call `write(toFile:)`, which will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks I did it as you suggested. but looks that's not the underlying problem. I now use nsuserdefaults as I only need to save a little data.